# Setting up an OpenVPN client to connect to the Synology diskstation VPN Server without redirecting all the traffic

Tags: vpn, openvpn, synology, vpn-client

I followed [official Synology documentation](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/VPNCenter/vpn_setup) and I created an OpenVPN Server to connect remotely to a NAS, that is in a LAN with its `NAS_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS`. The VPN server configuration is like the following one:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to connect from my Mac via Tunnelblick following [their instructions](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Network/How_do_I_connect_to_Synology_VPN_Server_via_Mac). In particular, they say:

> Open the exported file openvpn.ovpn with TextEdit and replace YOUR_SERVER_IP with the public IP address of your Synology NAS. If you wish to send all traffic over VPN, remove # from #redirect-gateway def1.

[image]

Here is my `VPNConfig.ovpn`:

```
dev tun
tls-client

remote YOUR_SERVER_IP 1194

pull

# If you want to connect by Server's IPv6 address, you should use
# "proto udp6" in UDP mode or "proto tcp6-client" in TCP mode
proto udp

script-security 2


comp-lzo

reneg-sec 0

cipher AES-256-CBC

auth SHA512

auth-user-pass
```

**I do not want to reroute all the traffic to the VPN**, I just wanna route requests to my `NAS_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS`.

If I leave `#redirect-gateway def1` commented, the VPN seems working this way. This is what I want but I cannot understand why it happens, since I've never specified the `NAS_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS` anywhere in the config file.

Can you folks help me understand how things work under the hood?

Comment: Please show VPN server configuration. OpenVPN can *push* routes (and other settings) to clients, that's why, even while you didn't configured any on the client, they may appear after connecting. Also, please **paste all configs as text**. Don't use pictures for that. Replace a screenshot with the copy-paste text. That way it will be indexed by search engines and may eventually help someone else. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @NikitaKipriyanov I updated the original post w/ the client config file. It's nothing more than the default one you can download from the Synology VPN Server. My question is: how does my OS know that **only the IP `NAS_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS`** need to be rerouted through the VPN? If I understand correctly your suggestion, it is a kind of static route pushed back to my OS after the first connection to the VPN Server

Comment: OpenVPN itself is configured with text config file or command line options (or both). I meant I need those to help. Synology did a GUI which obscures these things, because it isn't clear what GUI elements correspond to which OpenVPN options. What this "Allow other clients to access  server's LAN" does? Does it push any routes? I'll say it again, that is possible in OpenVPN, but since you showed DSM config and not OpenVPN's one it is only a speculation. From this screenshot I just can't tell how your OpenVPN server is configured.

Comment: I see, but I don’t know how where to get the file you requested in the Synology ecosystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you've selected the `Allow clients to access server's LAN` options on the NAS side.

This means that upon connecting, the server (NAS) pushes down a route like `NAS_LOCAL_NETWORK is reachable via NAS_VPN_IP_ADDRESS`.

So when you try to contact `NAS_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS` your client identifies it as part of `NAS_LOCAL_NETWORK` and sends it to `NAS_VPN_IP_ADDRESS`. On the other end of the tunnel, your NAS knows that `NAS_LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS` doesn't need to be routed but is a local ip address, i.e. answers the request directly.

Comment: Hi. I've just update the original question w/ more details such as the VPN Server configuration. Yes, I selected that option. How can I check the extra routes injected upon the connection to the VPN server?

Comment: Either you set the client logging level (add `verb 3` to the config) and check the log (search for `PUSH: Received control message`), or you observe your routing table (`ip ro` Linux, `route print` Win, `netstat -rn` macOS).